# fs.readFile is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, node-modules, fs

I'm new to **Angular** and **Nodejs**. I'm currently developing a Web Application using Angular 5. I want to create a node module and publish it to **npm** and use it in my app. This module should read from an **xml** file to create some objects. It always gives me the same error ( `fs_1.readFile is not a function`). I don't know if it 's possible to read from **xml** inside the node module.

I'm trying to create an npm package, within this package there will be an xml file. inside one of the classes of this package I want to read the xml file.

[Here is screenshot from @types/node module. The function exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqxzg.jpg)

Here is my `index.js` :

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const fs_1 = require("fs");
const xml_js_1= require("xml-js");

class PasswordsConfiguration{
  constructor(){
    this.passwords=new Array();
    this.companies=new Array();
    this._json = undefined;
    this.readXML()

  }
  readXML(){
    var name,isFunction, maskAND, maskOR, key, defaultValue,companyName,displayedName;
    try{

        fs_1.readFile('./passwords-config.xml', 'utf8', (err, data) => {

        // just neglect the rest of the code, it doesn#t enter this function.
        if (err) {

        }
        else {
            this._json = xml_js_1.xml2js(data, {
                compact: true,
                nativeType: true,
                ignoreDeclaration: true,
                ignoreComment: true
            });

            this._json.Configuration.Passwords.every((password) => {
              name =password._attributes.name;
              isFunction=Boolean(password._attributes.isFunction);
              maskAND = parseInt(password._attributes.maskAND,16);
              maskOR = parseInt(password._attributes.maskOR,16);
              key = password._attributes.key;
              defaultValue = parseInt(password._attributes.defaultValue,16);
              this.passwords.push(new Password(name,isFunction, maskAND, maskOR, key, defaultValue));

            });
            this._json.Configuration.Companies.every((company) => {
              companyName =company._attributes.name;
              displayedName =company._attributes.displayedName;
              this.companies.push(new Company(companyName,displayedName));
            });
        }
    });
    }catch(e){

    }

  }
}
exports.PasswordsConfiguration = PasswordsConfiguration;
```

Here is the index.d.ts

```
export declare class PasswordsConfiguration {
  private _json:any;
  passwords:Array<Password>;
  companies:Array<Company>;
  constructor();
  readXML():void;
}
```

So is this functionality applicable? What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Do you mean **`fs_1.readFile` is not a function**? Because I don't see `fs.readFile` in your code.

Comment: Maybe this is the JS compiled from Typescript and fs.readFile is in the ts file.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `fs` module installed (look at your `node_modules` folder) ?

Comment: @Air1 `fs` is a native node module.  It is available in all versions of node and wouldn't be in the local `node_modules`.

Comment: Are you trying to use `fs` client side; i.e. in a browser?  That isn't possible.

Comment: fs module is there in @types/node and I can see export function

Comment: @zero298 I'm trying to create an npm package, within this package there will be an xml file. inside one of the classes of this package I want to read the xml file.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes I mean fs_1.readFile is not a function

Comment: Again, do you expect this code to run inside of a browser such as IE, Firefox, or Chrome?

Comment: can you past us the typescript version of this please

Comment: @zero298 yes, I'm running it on Chrome.

Comment: Unrelated, but for such a small chunk of code, I find it quite difficult to read.

Comment: Then this isn't possible.  `fs` is a node.js module.  A browser has no concept of a file system.  It cannot be used.

Comment: @mhs301 ... While there are fs-ish modules for the browser, they're not what you think they are.

Comment: @JoshStevens I have edited the question.

Comment: @zero298 Is there any other way to pass a configuration file with the package, and the class reads from it? or I have to rewrite the xml file manually in the code

Comment: @mhs301 that is not the typescript file.. where is your `index.ts`

Comment: @DaveNewton what are my options to pass a configuration data with the npm package?

Comment: @JoshStevens I don't have in the package index.ts ... from the client side I import the class and create new instance of the object and the function is called in the constructor as u can see.

Comment: This question is all over the place, sorry it's not clear enough for me to help you.